# Convert list of string to list of synsets

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, synset

Convert List of String to List of objects of type synset.

I have tried to split and add but was not able to type cast it to sysnet type.

```
    inp="[Synset<'history.n.02'>,Synset<'long.n.02'>]"
```

I should get output as

```
    [Synset<'history.n.02'>,Synset<'long.n.02'>]
```

such that output should be **list of synsets**.
For understanding [synsets](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **wn.synset()**

```
inp="[Synset<'history.n.02'>,Synset<'long.n.02'>]"
inp=inp[1:-1]
for i in inp.split(','):
    val= i[8:-2]
    print wn.synset(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

words = ['dog','cat']
wn_words = [wn.synsets(word) for word in words]
```

Comment: Actually, I want to avoid this computation of  the sysnet again and again.So this will not be apt

Comment: @Dpseudo Coders The synset calculation is done once for each word in `words`

Comment: Ya but,is there a way which can be faster to convert string to synset object

Comment: if you can suggest way to convert "Synset<'history.n.02'>" to synset object

Comment: Not sure I understand. What is the type of the elements in `inp` list? What is the desired type?

Comment: I mentioned its synsets